# jsonb_each_text(jsonb) returns jsonb, not text

Tags: postgresql, json, set-returning-functions

According to [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) , `jsonb_each_text(jsonb)` returns

> setof key text, value text

but if you `pg_typeof(value)` on result it shows `jsonb`, Eg:

```
SELECT *, pg_typeof(key) AS type_key, pg_typeof(value) AS type_value
FROM jsonb_each('{"2": "-200.08"}');

 key |   value   | type_key | type_value 
-----+-----------+----------+------------
 2   | "-200.08" | text     | jsonb
```

**UPDATE:**
I have mistaken docs for `jsonb_each_text` instead of `jsonb_each`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## `jsonb_each` is not `jsonb_each_text`

No, you're calling `jsonb_each` and you're referencing the docs for `jsonb_each_text` It shows

On `\dfS json_each_text`,

```
      Name       | Result data type |              Argument data types              |
-----------------+------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
 jsonb_each_text | SETOF record     | from_json jsonb, OUT key text, OUT value text 
 jsonb_each      | SETOF record     | from_json jsonb, OUT key text, OUT value jsonb
```

Making that adjustment to call `jsonb_each_text`

```
SELECT *, pg_typeof(key) AS type_key, pg_typeof(value) AS type_value
FROM jsonb_each_text('{"2": "-200.08"}');

 key |  value  | type_key | type_value 
-----+---------+----------+------------
 2   | -200.08 | text     | text
```

Comment: According to postgresql docs, `json_each_text(json)` returns `setof key text, value text`, but `json_each(json)` returns `setof key text, value json`

Comment: Just that right after I posted and changed the answer.

Comment: Yes, I've seen now.

Comment: was I blind?...